# When do we use "Hose" like a plurale tantum?

Tags: grammar, noun, grammatical-number

Unlike *"trousers"* in English we use *"Hose"* in both, singular and plural forms. This also includes situations where we use it like a *[plurale tantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum)* (even though it is none in German). Sometimes we can readily replace the plural form by a singular, but in other cases this does not work.

> - Sie trägt enge Hosen - Sie trägt eine enge Hose
>     Heute habe ich mir [ein paar] neue Hosen gekauft - Ich brauchte eine neue Hose
>     Pupsi hat die Hosen voll [gemacht] - Pupsi hat die Hose voll [gemacht]
> - Die Hose hängt immer im Schrank - *no plurale tantum*
>     Meine Hose ist sauber - *no plurale tantum*
> - Bei Hempels hat "sie" die Hosen an - *no singular*
>     Jetzt muss der Vorstand die Hosen runter lassen - *no singular (!)*

Is there any pattern that helps me to decide when to use singular and when to use plural?

Comment: Ähhh, was ist jetzt deine Frage? Die Antwort auf dein letzten Satz ist: Wenn du von einer Hose redest, nimmst du Singular, sonst Plural. Aber ich weiß, dass das nicht deine Intention ist.

Comment: @Em1: Er muss die Hosen (nicht Hose) runterlassen. Sie hat die Hosen (nicht Hose) an bei den Hempels.

Comment: Wenn bildlich verwendet, scheint Plural mit Singularverwendung bevorzugt zu sein (<-- ich hätte Politiker werden sollen, oder Anwalt).

Comment: @JohnSmithers Auch wenn die Gruppe *Die Toten Hosen* heisst, spricht man nur von *tote Hose*, demnach gilt deine Feststellung nicht.

Comment: Außerdem heisst es imho *etw. geht in die Hose*, nicht Hosen. Und es ist Jacke wie Hose (wieder kein Plural). Man macht auf *dicke Hose*.

Comment: Und beide sind möglich/richtig: *Hose runterlassen* und *Hosen runterlassen*.

Comment: @Em1: Ich würde "Hose runterlassen" niemals bildlich verwenden, sondern als direkte Aufforderung verstehen, es wirklich zu tun.

Comment: @JohnSmithers Na gut, meinetwegen kann man darüber noch streiten. Aber was ist mit *Hose(n) gestrichen voll haben*?

Comment: @Em1: Es hat seinen Grund, dass ich noch keine Antwort verfasst habe ;)

Comment: Ich glaube, dass es keine allgemeine Regel gibt. Dass muss bei jeder Verwendung neu entschieden werden. Die Frage ist dann eigentlich, will man sich auf *die eine Hose* beschränken oder gilt es für *alle Hosen*. Z.b. *Eigentlich hat sie die Hosen an, aber heute ist er der Chef.* vs "Normalerweise bestimmt sie das Geschehen, aber heute hat er die Hose an.* oder *Immer wenn eine Klausur ansteht, hat er die Hosen voll.* vs *Eigentlich hat sie kein Lampenfieber, aber bei 50.000 Zuschauern hat sie doch die Hose voll.*

Comment: @Em1: Das hört sich nach einer wunderbaren Antwort an :)

Comment: @userunknown Du hast Recht. Siehe auch: [Kleidungsstück, das den Körper unterhalb der Taille (bis zu den Füßen) bedeckt und dabei jedes Bein einzeln umschließt. Der Plural ist auch für den Singular gebräuchlich, da eine Hose aus zwei Schläuchen (Hosen) besteht (vgl. Herkunft).](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hose). Antworte!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich denke der Plural, *"Hosen"*, ist eine inzwischen alte und (im Gegensatz zum Englischen) inzwischen ***seltene Form*** für ein einzelnes Kleidungsstück. Es ist sicherlich kein Zufall, daß das deutsche "Hose" orthographisch identisch zu einem englischen Wort für "Schlauch" ist — eine Hose besteht immerhin im Wesentlichen aus ***zwei Schläuchen***.

Eine (vor knapp 100 Jahren geborene) ***Großmutter*** von mir hat ***immer den Plural*** "Hosen" verwendet. Ihr "Zieh deine Hosen an, Junge, wir wollen los!" habe ich noch ziemlich genau im Ohr, und es war definitive keine Aufforderung, mehrere Hosen anzuziehen, sondern lediglich die eine, die sie mir hingelegt hatte. Auch in Büchern wurde (wird?) bei der Beschreibung der Kleidung von Charakteren oftmals der Plural verwendet ("seine Hosen waren von einem verblichenem dunkelblauen Stoff"), wenn *nicht* die gesamte dem jeweiligen Charakter zur Verfügung stehende Auswahl an Beinkleidern gemeint war, sondern nur die momentan getragene einzelne Hose. (Oder wenn die eine momentan getragene Hose die einzige ist.)

Meines Erachtens etwas gebräuchlicher als der simple Plural *"Hosen"* ist heute noch ***"ein Paar Hosen"***. Den Satz "Ich habe mir ein Paar Hosen gekauft" verwende ich bestimmt auch immer noch manchmal, wenn ich mich auf ein einzelnes erworbenes Kleidungsstück beziehe.

Ich weiß keine Regel, wann die eine oder andere Variante zu verwenden ist, kann mir aber kaum vorstellen, daß es außer bei stehenden Redewendungen ("In diesem Haus hat *sie* die Hosen an.") Fälle gibt, wo der grammatische Singular, auf ein einzelnes Kleidungsstück angewendet, unpassend ist.
Insofern kann man sicherlich immer den einfachen Singular ***"Hose"*** verwenden. Die Benutzung dieses Singulars (ebenso wie "ein Paar Hosen") verhindert auch Mißverständnisse, ob ein oder mehrere Exemplare gekauft wurden.

Answer (score 3):

`Die Hosen anhaben` bedeutet dasselbe wie `den Hut aufzuhaben`. Es ist kein bestimmtes Exemplar gemeint, und eben eine Besonderheit der Hosen, dass diese wohl vormals aus zwei Teilen bestanden, weswegen sich für das, was wir heute eine Hose nennen, früher der Begriff "die Hosen" einbürgerte, was sich in Redewendungen länger hält, als im sonstigen Sprachgebrauch, wo "die Hosen anziehen" selten geworden ist.

"Die Hosen voll haben" heißt beide (Beine, s. a. die Beinkleider), nicht den ganzen Schrank.

Wie man an der Windhose sieht, bezeichnet die Hose ein schlauchförmiges Gebilde.

Vorsicht wg. des seltenen Gebrauchs jenseits von Sprichwörtern ist bei "ein Paar Hosen kaufen" vs. "ein paar Hosen kaufen" geboten. Die Doppeldeutigkeit kann leicht übersehen werden.

Answer (score 2):

[sbi](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4008/1366) made the right point. The plural "Hosen" was generally used in the past. [The Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hose), which is the standard dictionary for german language, says the correct singular form ist "die Hose". On a sidenote it declares "häufig auch im Plural mit singularischer Bedeutung", which is not a very clear rule to follow. Coming from a younger generation my linguistic intuition tells me that the plural form in singular meaning has become a little bit outdated. I would expect either older people using it or people in rural areas in colloquial language.

So my advice is to use "Hose" like every other noun. If you refer to a single "Hose" you use "Hose" and if you refer to more than one you use the plural "Hosen".

You only have to be careful with figures of speech because the singular is often replaced with the plural (but not has to).

Analyzing your examples:

- "Sie trägt enge Hosen" You are talking about all of her trousers, thats why you have to use plural
- "Sie trägt eine enge Hose" You are refering to the trousers she is wearing at the moment that is why you use singular
- "Die Hose hängt immer im Schrank" Again you are refering to a single pair of trousers
- "Meine Hose ist sauber" Talking about the trousers you are wearing at the moment
- "Bei Hempels hat sie die Hosen an" Thats plural because of the figure of speech "die Hosen anhaben" which means to be dominant. In this case the singular is never used.
- "Jetzt muss der Vorstand die Hosen runter lassen" Again plural because of the figure of speech "die Hosen runter lassen" which means to show everything you have. Note that this figure of speech also exists in singular when talking about only one person. In that case it doesn't matter which you use.

"Pupsi hat die Hosen voll [gemacht]" is a little more complicated which i will now explain:

- "die Hose(n) voll" is a figure of speech which means to be very scared. You can use both singular and plural here.
- "die Hose(n) voll gemacht" is a figure of speech which has two different meanings. If you are referring to the same as before, that somebody was very scared, again both singular and plural can be used. The other use of this figure is when a person (usually a baby or a very old person) really defecated his pants. There you want use the singular form. (You can use the plural too but it sounds unnatural)

Note that the quantifier "ein paar" is always followed by the plural and means a few. The quantifier "ein Paar" is also always followed by the plural and means two. But in the special case of "ein Paar Hosen" it only means one pair of trousers. That is the same for all clothes (like socks) where logical affiliation to two duplicate body parts is given.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. IME the grammatical plural is still in more or less regular (if rare and decreasing) use for the singular object, and not only in ancient figures of speech (see [my answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/when-do-we-use-hose-like-a-plurale-tantum/4008#4008)). And shirts also have two arms but still nobody ever uses the plural to refer to a single one.

Comment: While trousers a generally linked to your two legs, a shirt is linked to your upper body. That is why a muscle-shirt, which is not even covering your arms is still considered a shirt. I was referring mainly to shoes, trousers and socks.

Answer (score 0):

Dort wo ich aufwuchs (Graz, Steiermark) wurde, wenn nur eine einzelne Hose gemeint war, immer und ausnahmslos der Singular verwendet, so wie das auch bei eigentlich allen anderen Wörtern üblich ist. Als ich als Erwachsener das erste Mal hörte, dass jemand den Plural verwendet hat um von einer einzelnen Hose zu sprechen, hielt ich das für einen Fehler. Auch heute noch gehört die Pluralform, wenn damit nur ein Stück gemeint ist, bei mir nur zum passiven Wortschatz und irritiert mich nach wie vor wenn ich sie höre oder lese.

Ich möchte daher auf die beiden Beispiele eingehen, die in der Frage als vermeintliche Pluraliatantum bezeichnet wurden:

> Bei Hempels hat sie die Hosen an.

Dieser Beispielsatz widerstrebt mir aus mehreren Gründen, die vor allem mit den Unterschieden zwischen deutschem Deutsch und österreichischen Deutsch zu tun haben (siehe unten). Was aber die Hose betrifft, würde ich diesen Satz so interpretieren, dass im Schrank von Familie Hempel mehrere Hosen hängen, die nach und nach (also nicht gleichzeitig) von Frau Hempel getragen werden, wenn auch nur im übertragenen Sinn.

Vor 100 Jahren (und davor) hatten zum einen nur die Männer das Sagen, und zum anderen waren Männer auch die einzigen, die Hosen trugen. (Plural weil jeder mehrere Hosen hat die er hintereinander trägt. Ersetze "Hose" durch "Hemd", "Jacke" usw. um das zu überprüfen.) Wenn nun eine Frau in der Familie den Ton angab, füllte sie die Rolle aus, die den Männern zugedacht war, und das war eben die Rolle eines Hosen-Trägers, daher war sie es nun, die - im übertragenen Sinn - die Hosen (nämlich die, die im Haushalt vorrätig waren) anhatte (zeitlich hintereinander).

Wenn ich beobachte, dass in einer bestimmten Situation Frau Hempel dazu neigt ihrem Mann ihre Vorlieben aufzuzwängen, ohne andeuten zu wollen dass das möglicherweise häufiger der Fall ist, und wenn ich unbedingt die veraltete Hosen-Analogie verwenden wollte, würde ich sagen:

> Der arme Herr Hempel kann sich in diesem einen Punkt nicht gegenüber seiner Frau durchsetzen. Da hat heute Frau Hempel die Hose an.

---

> Jetzt muss der Vorstand die Hosen runter lassen.

In der alltäglichen Umgangssprache, die im Osten Österreichs gesprochen wird, enden Kleidungsstücke auch im Singular gerne auf -n:

> Ich hab' mit heut' eine Hos'n gekauft.
>   Zieh' dir dei Jack'n an, es ist kalt.
>   Wo ist der zweite Sock'n, der zu dem da dazu passt? (*Der Sock'n* ist bei uns im Dialekt männlich, ebenso übrigens wie *der Schraufn*. Hochdeutsch: *die Socke* bzw. *die Schraube*)

Daher habe ich »die Hos'n runter lassen« auch immer als Singular verstanden. In der Hochsprache würde ich aber das n durch ein e ersetzen:

> Jetzt muss der Vorstand die Hose runter lassen.

---

**Nachtrag zu *Bei Hempels ...***
(off-topic, aber ich weiß nicht wo ich das sonst hinschreiben sollte)

1. »Hempel« ist ein typisch deutscher Name, der in Österreich so gut wie gar nicht vorkommt. Das trifft auf viele Namen zu, unter anderem auch auf »Schlüter«, und weil diese typisch deutschen Namen in Österreich so fremd und exotisch klingen, wurde Ende 2014 aus dem Milchschnitte-Werbespot »Großer Tag, kleine Pause«, der anfangs im Österreichischen Fernsehen unverändert in der bundesdeutschen Version lief, die Erwähnung der »Frau Schlüter« herausgeschnitten, weil sich kaum ein Österreicher mit dieser Werbung identifizieren konnte. (Das ebenfalls un-österreichische »wo wir lang müssen« blieb drinnen weil man es nicht ersatzlos rausschneiden konnte, sondern den Spot neu hätte drehen müssen was offenbar zu teuer war.) Solche Namen akzeptiert man hierzulande natürlich bei echten Personen, aber nicht dann, wenn man Allerweltsnamen erwartet, die eine klar erkennbare Platzhalterfunktion haben. Solche Namen wären in Österreich: Huber, Pichler, Wagner usw.
   In einem Beispielsatz wäre also nicht von Frau Hempel, sondern von eher von Frau Huber die Rede.
2. Familiennamen werden in Österreich nicht in den Plural gesetzt. Es gibt also keine Hempels und auch keine Hubers. Man spricht von der Familie Hempel und der Familie Huber.

Der Beispielsatz »Bei Hempels hat sie die Hosen an.« würde bei uns also lauten:

> In der Familie Huber hat sie die Hosen an.

Zu ergänzen ist, dass deutsche Fernsehsender, die in Österreich gesehen werden, und deutsche Zeitschriften, die den österreichischen Markt überschwemmen (und österreichischen Verlagen das Leben schwer machen), das österreichische Deutsch allmählich verdrängen. Das führt nicht nur dazu, dass man in Österreich seit 10 oder 15 Jahren neben Erdäpfeln und Paradeisern auch Kartoffeln und Tomaten kaufen kann, sondern auch dazu, dass unter anderem die Pluralbildung von Familiennamen neuerdings auch hierzulande gelegentlich Anwendung findet.